# SSL Certificate Verify Failed Error When Configuring BarmanBackupConfig in CNPG Deployment

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, ssl-certificate, barman, cloudnative-pg

### Issue

I'm trying to configure the `BarmanObjectStoreConfiguration` for my Cloud Native PostgreSQL (CNPG) deployment, but I'm encountering an SSL validation error. Here's the error message I'm getting:

"SSL validation failed for <S3_ENDPOINT/BUCKET> [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)"

### Version

- PostgreSQL: `imageName: ghcr.io/cloudnative-pg/postgresql:16.0`
- CNPG Operator Helm Chart: `0.19.1`
- CNPG Operator: `1.21.1`

### What I did ?

I have set up the barmanObjectStore configuration in my CNPG Cluster YAML file as follows:

```yaml
apiVersion: postgresql.cnpg.io/v1
kind: Cluster
metadata:
  name: cnpg-db
spec:
    backup:
    barmanObjectStore:
      destinationPath: "s3://<BUCKET_NAME>"
      endpointURL: https://<ENDPOINT>
      endpointCA: # Seems doing nothing ?
        name: cnpg-s3-cred-password
        key: CA_CERT
      s3Credentials:
        accessKeyId:
          name: cnpg-s3-cred-password
          key: ACCESS_KEY_ID
        secretAccessKey:
          name: cnpg-s3-cred-password
          key: ACCESS_SECRET_KEY
      wal:
        compression: gzip
        encryption: AES256
      data:
        compression: gzip
        encryption: AES256
    retentionPolicy: 30d
  env: # Trying to manually set CA_BUNDLE because params doesn't work
    - name: REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE # Supposed to be used with Azure Blob Storage
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: cnpg-s3-cred-password
          key: CA_CERT
    - name: AWS_CA_BUNDLE # Supposed to be used with AWS S3 (or compatible services)
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: cnpg-s3-cred-password
          key: CA_CERT
```

have verified that the cnpg-s3-cred-password secret contains the correct CA certificate, access key ID, and secret access key. I'm not sure what I'm missing or doing wrong.

Could someone please help me resolve this SSL validation error and successfully configure the barmanBackupConfig for my CNPG deployment? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a solution to my issue, the `AWS_CA_BUNDLE` should be the path to the CA cert file (according to the Boto documentation: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#using-environment-variables) and the `endpointCA` parameters are just in charge of dropping the ca into `/run/certificates/backup-barman-ca.crt`.

So the solution was to:

- set `AWS_CA_BUNDLE=/run/certificates/backup-barman-ca.crt`

Here is the corrected yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: postgresql.cnpg.io/v1
kind: Cluster
metadata:
  name: cnpg-db
spec:
    backup:
    barmanObjectStore:
      destinationPath: "s3://<BUCKET_NAME>"
      endpointURL: https://<ENDPOINT>
      endpointCA:
        name: cnpg-s3-cred-password
        key: CA_CERT
      s3Credentials:
        accessKeyId:
          name: cnpg-s3-cred-password
          key: ACCESS_KEY_ID
        secretAccessKey:
          name: cnpg-s3-cred-password
          key: ACCESS_SECRET_KEY
      wal:
        compression: gzip
        encryption: AES256
      data:
        compression: gzip
        encryption: AES256
    retentionPolicy: 30d
  env:
    - name: AWS_CA_BUNDLE
      value: /run/certificates/backup-barman-ca.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the certificate provided at `endpointCA` has the **full certificate chain** if it's not using public CAs.

If you have `requestAutoCert` (enabled by default) in your MinIO Tenant the certificate will be signed by the Kubernetes self-signed CA.

That certificate for that CA is automatically available in `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt`, but that's not helpful in our case as we cannot instruct the machine to use it. You can alternatively retrieve it from the `kube-root-ca.crt` `ConfigMap` in the `kube-system` namespace.

The following would create a `kube-root-ca.crt` secret in your namespace containing the only certificate needed under the `ca.crt` key that you can then expose via the `endpointCA` option.

```bash
kubectl -n $NAMESPACE create secret generic kube-root-ca.crt --from-literal=ca.crt="$(kubectl -n kube-system get configmaps kube-root-ca.crt -o jsonpath='{.data.ca\.crt}')" --dry-run=client -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

I'm using the CloudNativePG [`cluster`](https://github.com/cloudnative-pg/charts/tree/main/charts/cluster) chart and the following configuration was all I needed:

```yaml
mode: standalone
cluster:
  instances: 1
backups:
  enabled: true
  provider: s3
  endpointURL: "https://minio.minio.svc.cluster.local"
  endpointCA:
    name: kube-root-ca.crt
    key: ca.crt
  wal:
    encryption: ""
  data:
    encryption: ""
  s3:
    bucket: "mybucket"
    path: "/v1"
    accessKey: "minio"
    secretKey: "minio123"
    region: "local"
```

Note that it doesn't need `AWS_CA_BUNDLE` and from what I can tell the environment variable has no effect.